# Super constructor call in Blackberry Screen classes

Tags: java, compiler-construction, blackberry

Why is the super() constructor recommended to be called when extending any of the RIM Screen classes? It was my understanding that the no-arg constructor of any super class was implicitly called from any class that extends it, am I wrong?

Comment: Sure, here's RIM's hello world demo:

http://pastebin.com/m48ebd7de

Original source:
http://na.blackberry.com/eng/developers/resources/developer_labs.jsp#tab_tab_jde

Comment: Since this is a Hello World example, I think the author was being explicit. The example doesn't say that it's actually *required*.

Comment: True, but it pops up in several other examples and in most of their PDF documentation. I'm confident there's some reason, even if it's just a company wide style policy.

It seems to make sense in the cases where the field classes explicitly need a long argument to set their style, (you'll often see super(0) ) but for general use it's just a little baffling.

Comment: Showing it in examples isn't quite the same thing as it being *recommended*.

Comment: I'm still stumbling across it, page 20 of this getting started guide:
http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/5813/BlackBerry_Java_Development_Environment_getting_started.pdf

Reads:
2.In the first line of the constructor for the inner class, invoke the constructor of the MainScreen class.
super();

Could it just be a strictly adhered to code styling?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

super() will be called by default constructor no matter if you implement it or not.

It's easy to test. Just a couple classes:

```
class ClassA {
    public ClassA() {
        UiApplication.getUiApplication().invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                Dialog.inform("ClassA()");
            }
        });
    }
}

class ClassB extends ClassA {
    public ClassB() {
        super();
        UiApplication.getUiApplication().invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                Dialog.inform("ClassB()");
            }
        });
    }
}

class ClassC extends ClassA {

}

class ClassD extends ClassA {
    public ClassD() {
        UiApplication.getUiApplication().invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                Dialog.inform("ClassD()");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

And test app:

```
class Scr extends MainScreen {

    protected void makeMenu(Menu menu, int instance) {
        super.makeMenu(menu, instance);

        menu.add(new MenuItem("class A", 0, 0) {
            public void run() {
                ClassA a = new ClassA();
            }
        });
        menu.add(new MenuItem("class B", 0, 0) {
            public void run() {
                ClassB b = new ClassB();
            }
        });
        menu.add(new MenuItem("class C", 0, 0) {
            public void run() {
                ClassC c = new ClassC();
            }
        });
        menu.add(new MenuItem("class D", 0, 0) {
            public void run() {
                ClassD d = new ClassD();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

So you see, there is no difference between dialog calls in ClassA() and ClassC(), also no diffs between ClassB() and ClassD().

Answer (score 0):

No, you're absolutely right. Some people like putting it in explicitly for clarity - I'm not a fan, personally.

Can you link to such a recommendation, so we can check there's nothing more subtle going on?

Answer (score 0):

RIM has implemented their own Java VM and compiler. It may or may not implement sub-classing exactly like the standard Java VM and compiler. If RIM recommends doing it a certain way, I would simply follow it.

If you really want to omit the call to `super()` I would test it out rather than make assumptions.

However, I can't find any reference to official docs saying you need to do this. [Field](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.5.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/Field.html), [Manager](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.5.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/Manager.html) and [Screen](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.5.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/Screen.html) class javadocs don't mention it.

Comment: Good point. I've excluded it from my code quite a few times with no apparent ill-effects. Obviously I should include it to play it safe but I'd still like to know the reasoning behind it.

Comment: Umm why did you accept this answer? First you are skeptic then accept an answer which says: Just to make sure call `super()`

Comment: Sorry, new here, thought there was a need to select one of the answers as accepted. Your implication that the custom RIM VM may need it sounded like a good enough reason to shut up and type super(); - I'll unselect your answer (no offence) in the hope that a RIM developer may be able to shed some light.

Comment: The call to super() will be in the emitted bytecode, so it's a compiler matter rather than a VM matter.

Comment: Good point, however RIM also has a proprietary compiler, which may or may not behave the same as the standard one.

Answer (score 0):

You are right about the no-arg constructor being implicitly called. And I'm pretty damn sure that also the RIM JRE does it this way.

I guess what you stumbled upon is just the notorious "*super basic beginner hello world example*" which even calls `super()` explicitly so that every java noob understands that the constructor of `MainScreen` is called too.

I looked through most of the samples on the page you linked to and it looks like a copy-paste thing. If you for example checkout the `Using PIM functions` sample you will notice that here the call to `super()` is missing from the no-arg child constructor.